# Xcode 9.2 doesn't allow to select/change team

Tags: ios, xcode, git, code-signing, xcode9.2

I have a few teams available for selection in Xcode 'Signing' section.
'Automatic signing' is on and I have one team selected by default when I open project.

Once I try to select another team from a list, my choice is reverted back to initial team. I can neither change team nor set it to 'None'.

[image: Here is screenshot showing my team choise]

I tried deleting all accounts and it results for 'Unknown Team' being selected, which is logical, however I still can not change it to None or to another account if I add one.

[image: Result after removing all accounts from XCode]

Additional details:

1. I am using Xcode 9.2 and it's React Native project.
2. This happens after I pull changes from repo where team has been set
   by another developer.
3. Another developer (commit owner) can not change his team to 'None' also.

So what are the reasons for that and how to change team?

Comment: Did you try unchecking **Automatically manage signing** and setting up the provisioning profiles manually?

Comment: @the4kman I believe this will cause trouble after I commit this and share to other developers. Though it might be somehow possible, I would like to use automatic signing and not to give up this feature.